# Show all files in documents library folder but limit access to individual files in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-permissions

is there a way in Sharepoint online to allow anyone who has access to a Sharepoint page to be able to view every single file within a folder but restrict certain users from actually viewing the files? So for example I have files inside of folder A for example:

Folder A

File 1.ext
File 2.ext
File 3.ext
I'd like for everyone to be able to view all 3 files inside of the folder structure, however I'd like to restrict access to file 3 and only allow certain users to view that file.

Currently if I restrict access to file 3 they will no longer see it in the document tree.

I've managed to do this when using vanity links in the "quick links" module on SP page builder when I link to a file. I'd like this same behavior to happen in my document root if possible. Please see the image below of what happens when linked to a SP file via a vanity link...

request access image

I think this is important because we have a large company with many users and I am unsure if we will grant access to every single file to all the right people. With this method users can request access. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello, is it not possible to move those confidential/ limited access files to a separate folder in the document library and manage the access separately for that folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you restrict the access of file 3 to some users, they will not be able to see file 3 in the folder structure, it's by default.

Comment: Allow users to view items in Document Library, but not open the files.

Comment: Per my test, if I have permission to view files in the SharePoint Online document library, I can open them online.